# Mapping Error after switching to SQL Server in NServicebus 5

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nservicebus

We used NServiceBus with RavenDB as Persistance.

Now we want to change that to SQL Server. So according to the documentation I changed the Persistance to NHibernatePersistence. Now I receive the following error:

> An association from the table MyInstanceOrderSagaData refers to an
>   unmapped class: My.Domain.Business.Order

The Configuration is this:
[code]

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
    {
        public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {
            configuration.EndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusEndpointName"]);
            configuration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
            configuration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
            configuration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
        }
    }
```

[app.config]

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ServiceBusEndpointName" value="MyOrdering.Saga" />
    <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Have you defined your NH mappings, so to map Saga types in NH?

Comment: @MauroServienti you don't need to create explicit mappings since it uses default NH type mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that NHibernate persistance uses dynamic mappings for your Saga data classes. Therefore, usual things apply like all members need to be virtual, all classes must have an Id property of type int and so on.

As for your exception, I could see that your Saga data contains a property of type that is your My.Domain.Business.Order type. This class is not mapped in NServiceBus NHibernate SessionFactory. I would heavily avoid any business-related references in your Saga data. I suggest that you create a DTO class to store your Order data and change the SagaData class to use it instead.